# Pulling from git from Jenkins on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssh, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on heroku (using the war file). I'm using bitbucket and have added the Jenkins service to my private repository, which is all working fine.

When I push my changes to the remote repository (bitbucket) everything fires just fine and a new build is started in Jenkins. This, however, is where my problem steps in. Jenkins can't pull from the remote repository, because the credentials aren't there.

I think I need to add an ssh key for jenkins, but how do I do this on heroku? Or is there another solution? Or is it just not possible at all.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the key into Git or have Jenkins fetch it from a persistent storage (SQL, NoSQL, environment variables, a cloud storage...). A good place to hook it is into a script you call from Procfile.

If you put it into the git (provided your Git is not public), tell Jenkins the key is found somewhere under the /app directory. That is probably the easiest way. If you cannot trust your key into Git, there are plenty of addons you can (ab)use.

Comment: Do you have an example add on which I could use to store the ssh key in Jenkins? I've tried one, but that didn't work

Comment: I was meaning Heroku addons that you can use as persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this tutorial could help http://www.agilogy.com/blog/heroku-staging-with-jenkins.html

Comment: Well, not really. Because Jenkins is running on Heroku, it doesn't need to push to heroku